# Access document files from QML

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml

I am writing a QML-App for Nexus 4 running Ubuntu touch. I have to access some files stored in /home/phablet/Documents. As I read here: 
[Use Pictures for an Image object in QML for Ubuntu Touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492398/use-pictures-for-an-image-object-in-qml-for-ubuntu-touch) this is not possible. In the AppArmor-File I entered "content-exchange" and "content-exchange-source". I still cannot access some local files.

Is there any possibility to read those files? I guess there must be a way, the music-app has access to music-files also!?

Thanks for helping
Jens

I tried this code:

```
Audio {
    id: player
    source: "file:///home/phablet/Documents/filename"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Is there any way to store my own files and access them? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least under rules for distribution through the app store.

As noted in the question you link to, the default application confinement on Ubuntu Touch restricts application to accessing files within their own silos.  You can change the confinement settings for your app, but this may not be accepted in the app store.  You could also give up on accessing these files directly and importing them through the content hub.  Details follow:

### 1) Importing files through the Content Hub

The [Content Hub](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/platform/guides/content-hub-guide/) provides a mechanism for transferring files from one application silo to another.  It can be used in a number of different ways, but you'd want to request an import of type documents.  Another app that can act as a source of documents will open and present a list of documents.  After the user selects one (or more), your application resumes and receives a signal with information on the documents, which have been copied to a location where you can access them.

Of course, most other applications are also subject to application confinement issues that keep them from accessing `~/Documents`.  However, the Document Viewer and File Manager are treated specially and given access to these files.  Both can act as Content Hub sources for documents.  Do note that the Document Viewer only supports some types of files.  The File Manager will export any type of file as a document, but it isn't installed by default.

(By the way, the same sort of mechanism allows the music app access to files in `~/Music`.  I find this decision to special-case the default apps rather problematic, not least of all because it means their code is useless for app authors to study.)

I've yet to find a good tutorial for using the Content Hub.  Instead, I'll post some code I wrote while trying to understand the Content Hub myself.  It lets you import documents either from the default provider or from one selected from the "ContentPeerPicker".

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "chtest.rschroll",
    "architecture": "all",
    "title": "chtest",
    "hooks": {
        "chtest": {
            "apparmor": "chtest.apparmor",
            "desktop":  "chtest.desktop"
        }
    },
    "version": "0.1",
    "framework" : "ubuntu-sdk-14.10"
}
```

**chtest.apparmor**

```
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking",
        "webview",
        "content_exchange"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.2
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.ListItems 0.1 as ListItem
import Ubuntu.Components.Popups 0.1
import Ubuntu.Content 0.1

MainView {
    id: mainView
    applicationName: "chtest.rschroll"

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    PageStack {
        id: pageStack
        Component.onCompleted: pageStack.push(root)

        Page {
            id: root
            title: i18n.tr("Import Content...")
            visible: false

            property var activeTransfer

            Column {
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: units.gu(2)
                Row {
                    height: units.gu(6)
                    anchors {
                        left: parent.left
                        right: parent.right
                        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    }
                    spacing: units.gu(3)
                    Button {
                        text: i18n.tr("... From default provider")
                        onClicked: {
                            root.activeTransfer = peer.request();
                        }
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: i18n.tr("... From choosen provider")
                        onClicked: {
                            pageStack.push(picker);
                        }
                    }
                }

                Label {
                    id: label
                    width: parent.width
                }
            }

            function importItems(items) {
                var string = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    string += i + ") " + items[i].url + "\n";
                    /* You may want to use items[i].move() to put the content somewhere permanent. */
                }
                label.text = string;
            }

            /* The ContentPeer sets the kinds of content that can be imported.  For some reason,
               handler must be set to Source to indicate that the app is importing.  This seems
               backwards to me. */
            ContentPeer {
                id: peer
                contentType: ContentType.Documents
                handler: ContentHandler.Source
                selectionType: ContentTransfer.Multiple
            }

            /* This is a GUI element that blocks the rest of the UI when a transfer is ongoing. */
            ContentTransferHint {
                anchors.fill: root
                activeTransfer: root.activeTransfer
            }

            /* Watch root.activeTransfer to find out when content is ready for our use. */
            Connections {
                target: root.activeTransfer
                onStateChanged: {
                    if (root.activeTransfer.state === ContentTransfer.Charged)
                        root.importItems(root.activeTransfer.items);
                }
            }
        }

        Page {
            id: picker
            visible: false
            /* This presents a grid of icons for apps that can give you content of the
               specified type. */
            ContentPeerPicker {
                id: peerPicker
                visible: parent.visible

                handler: ContentHandler.Source  // Source to get content, for some reason
                contentType: ContentType.Documents

                onPeerSelected: {
                    peer.selectionType = ContentTransfer.Multiple;
                    root.activeTransfer = peer.request();
                    pageStack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 2) Getting direct access to these files

If this seems like too much work, you can alter your app armor profile to grant additional access to the file system.  For example, to give your app read access to `~/Documents`, you would add to your app armor JSON file the line

```
"read_path": ["@{HOME}/Documents/"]
```

This will prevent your app from being automatically approved when you submit it to the official app store.  Instead, a human will have to look at it and decide whether to approve your application or not.  Sometimes they will (Log Viewer).  Sometimes they won't (my own ebook reader, Beru).  I haven't found any explanation as to why some apps are accepted and others aren't.

If you don't feel like gambling with the reviewer, or if you gamble and lose, you can submit your app to the [OpenStore](https://open.uappexplorer.com/submit), which publishes apps that cannot be published in the official store.

Answer (score 0):

Use the source: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~music-app-dev/music-app/refactor/files

apparmor.json there is:

```
{
    "policy_version": 1.3,
    "policy_groups": [
        "audio",
        "content_exchange",
        "music_files_read",
        "networking",
        "usermetrics"
    ],
    "read_path": [
        "@{HOME}/.cache/media-art/",
        "@{HOME}/.cache/mediascanner-2.0/",
        "/media/*/*/"
    ],
    "write_path": [
        "@{HOME}/Music/Imported/"
    ]
}
```